# Trying to copy text from other threads using a button

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, signals, clipboard

I am trying to figure out a way to make a decent copy to clipboard button function where I can copy text values from other threads inside a QTextEdit widget.
I pull the values from other threads and display them in a QTextEdit widget and have been trying to successfully copy to clipboard the contents of QTextEdit with a button but the only way I have been able to is my code below.
What I don't like is that the copy button makes a second call in order to copy the contents.
 Is there some way that the values can be stored from the first request using the `get_button` button and be available to copy with the copy button without having to make the same call all over again? Thanks.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    get_String = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.get_String.emit('Some text.')

class GUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.get_Button = QtGui.QPushButton('Get')
        self.c_Button = QtGui.QPushButton('Copy')
        self.text_Box = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.get_Button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.c_Button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.text_Box)
        vbox.addStretch()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.show()

        self._thread = WorkerThread()
        self.get_Button.clicked.connect(self.doIt)
        self._thread.get_String.connect(self.text_Box.append)
        self.c_Button.clicked.connect(self.copy_Stuff)

    def copy_Stuff(self):
        self.clipboard = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
        self._thread.get_String.connect(self.clipboard.setText)
        self._thread.start()

    def doIt(self):
        self.text_Box.clear()
        self.text_Box.setText('')
        self._thread.start()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was much easier than I initially thought. I was confused with how to copy text correctly because of all of the different ways I seen it done in other examples and posts. After reading the docs for awhile and trying to learn a bit more about pyqt I seen that it was as easy as using these 2 lines...

```
    self.text_Box.selectAll()
    self.text_Box.copy()
```

with those 2 lines and my button it seems to copy all the contents of the QTextEdit widget which is all I really needed. Here is my final working code in case someone else may find it useful.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    get_String = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.get_String.emit('Some text.')

class GUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.get_Button = QtGui.QPushButton('Get')
        self.c_Button = QtGui.QPushButton('Copy')
        self.text_Box = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.get_Button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.c_Button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.text_Box)
        vbox.addStretch()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.show()

        self._thread = WorkerThread()
        self.get_Button.clicked.connect(self.doIt)
        self._thread.get_String.connect(self.text_Box.append)
        self.c_Button.clicked.connect(self.copy_Stuff)

    def copy_Stuff(self):
        self.text_Box.selectAll()
        self.text_Box.copy()

    def doIt(self):
        self.text_Box.clear()
        self.text_Box.setText('')
        self._thread.start()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code example shows a simple working thread with signal that returns a value to the main, displays the value in a QTextEdit widget and how to copy all of the contents of a QTextEdit widget with a single button click.